# Custom Menu structure with Walker Class

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a simple menu of the following output  using `wp_nav_menu`. I would like to output one of the following type:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

The part that I care about really is the ability to insewrt  `<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>`  on  all menu items that have at dropdown menu.

NB: We have only two levels in the menu.

Comment: It will be better If you create a fiddle demo...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selectors `::after` in combination with the css property `content: ""`

```
 .menu__dropdown::after {
    content: " ▼"
}
```

Now just add the class .menu__dropdown to any menu `a` which has a submenu.
See live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8vndhv3j/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `.menu-item-has-children` to add the arrow icon with CSS.

If you need to add exactly `<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>` to the menu you can use javascript:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').append('<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>');
```

You can also create a custom walker class, that will give all the control about the menus HTML structure but is more complicated. Read about in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class

Comment: If you read my question exactly, I wanted to use a walker class

Comment: But then I don't understand very well your question, what is the problem? Have you already created the walker class? Can you put the code? We can't tell you how to modify the walker class without seeing the code